# Increment number in jQuery

Tags: javascript, strings

I have this number returned from an Ajax request: `015-0011-00001`. I want to increment the last part of the number (`00001`) on document load. What I did was get the last number and increment it then combine the numbers again. Is there a cleaner way of incrementing this number without slicing the number into many parts?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s5hapexc/2/)

```
var data = [{"code":"456100010011","incrementingnumber":"015-0011-00001"}];

var code = data[0].code;
var inc = data[0].incrementingnumber;
var res = code.slice(-4);
var inc1 = inc.slice(-4);
//alert(inc1);
var inc2 = parseInt(inc1) + 1;

var incrementvalue = ("00000" + inc2).slice(-5); // -> result: "0001"

console.log("015-" + res + "-" + incrementvalue);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{"code":"456100010011","incrementingnumber":"015-0011-00001"}];

var code = data[0].code,
    inc = data[0].incrementingnumber;
var inc1 = inc.split('-');
inc1[2] = ('00000' + ++inc1[2]).slice(-5);

document.write(inc1.join('-'));
```

You don't need the `code.slice`, but you'd still need to split your `incrementingnumber` value.

Comment: Let me ask one thing when you join the segments the previous value of element in index 2 will be replace automatically when you declare that in line `segments[2] = ("00000" + (+segments[2] + 1)).slice(-5);` . I just want to understand what happened. thank you for making cleaner than before.

Comment: `++inc1[2]` will increment the value at the 3rd index of `inc1` array. Since `.split` splits the string to an array; you have `inc1 = [[0] = '015', [1] = '0011', [2] = '00001']`. On increment, the preceeding `0`s get removed as the tpe changes from string to number. To format it back with 0-padding; we use slice. You can also use `.substring` instead of slice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [another approach](http://jsfiddle.net/s5hapexc/4/)

```js
var data = [{"code":"456100010011","incrementingnumber":"015-0011-00001"}];

var segments = data[0].incrementingnumber.split('-');
segments[2] = ("00000" + (+segments[2] + 1)).slice(-5);

document.write(segments.join('-'));
```

With very little context to go by, the last 4 digits of `code` appear to be the same as the second segment of `incrementingnumber`. I could very well assume they're the same, thus omitting `code` from being sliced.

Comment: Let me ask one thing when you join the segments the previous value of element in index 2 will be replace automatically when you declare that in line `segments[2] = ("00000" + (+segments[2] + 1)).slice(-5);` . I just want to understand what happened. thank you for making cleaner than before.

Comment: @Pekka Yes. The result of `("00000" + (+segments[2] + 1)).slice(-5)` will be assigned to `segments[2]`.